# How to display the number of years and month since a date using moment.js

Tags: momentjs

I want to display something like this :

member for `1 year, 8 month`

The example on the [momment.js](http://momentjs.com/)  web site is :

```
moment("20120620", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow(); // 2 years ago.
```

How to display also the number of month since the provided date ?

Like : **2 years, 6 months**

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the answer so I post it in case it can be useful for others:

```
var date = new Date(2011,5,24)   
var month = date.getMonth()
var year = date.getFullYear();

var dateString = moment(year, "YYYY").fromNow(true) + 
                 moment(month, "MM").fromNow(true)) +  " ago" 

console.log(dateString)
```